# How to echo the content of this code

Tags: php, html, wordpress, class, widget

i used this blog post to create a textfield in every widget in my wordpress site:
[Link](http://kreativkonzentrat.de/en/blog/wordpress-input-felder-und-klassen-zu-bestehenden-widgets-hinzufugen.html)

But i'm not that great with PHP so mo question is, how do i echo the value in this:

```
// widget area
function arphabet_widgets_init() {
    register_sidebar( array(
        'name' => 'footer widgets',
        'id' => 'footer_widgets',
        'before_widget' => '<li class="footer_widget">',
        'after_widget' => '</li>',
        'before_title' => '<h3 class="rounded"><i class="fa !!in here!! fa-fw"></i>',
        'after_title' => '</h3>',
    ) );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'arphabet_widgets_init' );
```

On the place where the !!in here!! text is right now

Thnx

Comment: Open page source and find `!!in here!!`. Its not part of front end.Its CSS class as you have put it in `class=""`.

Answer (score 1):

```
array(
  'name' => 'footer widgets',
  'id' => 'footer_widgets',
  'before_widget' => '<li class="footer_widget">',
  'after_widget' => '</li>',
  'before_title' => '<h3 class="rounded"><i class="fa '.$myVar.' fa-fw"></i>',
  'or',
  'before_title' => "<h3 class="rounded"><i class="fa $myVar fa-fw"></i>",
  'after_title' => '</h3>',
)
```

Just notice the double quotes where you can call variable or closure (not sure), or just concat a string to init your array.

```
$var = 1;
echo 'res : '.$var;
echo "res : $var";
```

both prints

```
res: 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, it was already verry helpfull, but the biggest problem i got is that i don't know where the content of the "testtext" is stored in ;)

Comment: consider seeing this http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php, and use like var_dump(func_get_args());die; or print_r(func_get_args());die;

Comment: I really don't understand that page, i just want to echo the content of the "texttest" field.